# Search and extract from a string (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I have two objects (JSON)

```
game : {id: "1XXXXXXXXX"}
```

I can get it like that to get a String with the ID

```
JSON.stringify(game.id)
"1XXXXXXXXX"
```

And I have another with lots of info, something like that

```
object{
    Mike{
        0{
           id:"236XXXXXXX"
           name:"vvvv"
           price:"23"
        }
        1{
           id:"1XXXXXXXXXX"
           name:"vvvvv"
           price:"56"
        }  
    } 
}
```

How can I get the price if I have the id but I have no idea about the location inside the object?

Comment: You don't need to do `JSON.stringify(game.id); "1XXXXXXXXX"` you can just do `game.id`?

Comment: The question has been closed, but you can also check out UnderscoreJS http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere

Comment: Related: [How to filter object array based on attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)